# Arc drawable ProgressBar

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I need help.
Long searched for a solution to this problem, but found nothing. Howe to make an arc `ProgressBar` using drawable resources?

Comment: What do you mean by arc ProgressBar?

Comment: Semicircular. Some understood?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/drawable_name"` or `setIndeterminateDrawable (Drawable d)`

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

[Custom ProgressBar](http://vsvydenko.blogspot.com/2011/06/customizing-android-progressbar.html)